# According to trinitarians, why can't there be multiple human persons who share one human substance?

Tags: theology, philosophy-of-religion, christianity

According to trinitarians, if there can be three divine persons within the Godhead who share one divine substance, why can't there be multiple human persons who share one human substance?

Comment: Some humans do have [multiple personalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_identity_disorder), but it is considered a disorder. That it takes the divine to harmonize them should not be surprising, even humans with different substances have trouble harmonizing their relationships. Christians say because we are sinful.

Comment: Hannah Arendt (sort of) posited that in the domain of inner thought, there is a second-person duality where we address ourselves as "you" as well as "I." And this is not just the linguistic difference between the second- and first-person perspectives. So Arendt might be interpreted as suggesting that everyone is at least two persons in one substance.

Comment: @KristianBerry Well personality is constituted by the duality of a conscious body plus a self that is conscious of the conscious body. That is not really new and matches the philosophies of Scheler, Plessner, Gehlen, Merleau-Ponty and others. Basically all philosophers that have some concept of bodily consciousness. The person is the unity of both, though, and no single part is sufficient for personhood.

Comment: @Philip Klöcking Why did you delete my answer? - My answer points out that the OP's question is based on a premiss which is rather dubious.

Comment: @JoWehler Because it was flagged for deletion. I agreed on the basis that it did not answer the question, but argued against its premises based on opinion, without resources.

Comment: @Philip Klöcking Part 1) of my reply gives my answer to the OP’s question: I follow Conifold’s answer. - Part 2) of my reply indicates: The OP grounds his question on a dubious premiss. If he does not support his premiss with an argument, the premiss has no relevance for the question. - Aside, I consider the premiss the more interesting part of the OP’s contribution. To me it seems worth a separate question/answer session. Do we agree: It is the task of the proponent to first support his premiss with an argument? After, it’s the job of the opponent to provide counter arguments.

Comment: Not sure how Christian doctrine defines person and substance, but would a "person" in utero count as two-in-one or even three-in-one in human "substance"? This would be about 5 percent of human population existing as overlapping "individuals" or "persons," which I suppose never comes up in philosophy because it is so overshadowed by the abortion question.

Comment: You are perhaps not understanding that there are NOT multiple human beings in the Trinity God head.  Jesus is the only one who expressed himself as a Human being. Christians believe Jesus is God who is just in human form.  God took human form o relayed to his creation & we can relate to Him.  There are multiple variations of beings  in the Trinity but it is really the SAME BEING. Each variant did something different & specific from the others separately. So humans like us can't do what a divine being can be. We can't stop being Humans or take lower forms. Jesus could do what we can't.

Comment: @Logikal you don't understand my question

Comment: @JoWehler It is also our task to read questions charitably. And my reading would be: given that there are theological and philosophical authors who accept the dogma of trinity, do they have any argument against the possibility of a similar "substance-sharing" of human selves?

Comment: The principle of charity? That's not in FAQ! This question is better suited for [ChristianitySE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/). Voted for closure.

Comment: @JoWehler According to Joseph Weissman, we are not philosophers, and so we are not here to argue positions at all, but merely describe the arguments of others. See [https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/friends-we-are-not-philosophers](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/friends-we-are-not-philosophers). I think while the dichotomy is not categorically enforceable, it's a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I strongly encourage the moderators to include a specific reference to the "principle of charity" with perhaps an explanation in the help center, perhaps under the code of conduct page. It's a foreign concept to some.

Comment: You people spend more time complaining about the questions being asked instead of ANSWERING PEOPLE'S QUESTIONS!!!! Like for the love of God, if you have a problem with the question, YOU DONT HAVE TO REPLY TO IT!!! No one's forcing you to reply to my question

Answer (score -1):

> If there can be three divine persons within the Godhead who share one divine substance, why can't there be multiple human persons who share one human substance?

I will assume that this refers to the Trinity. The Christian doctrine of the Trinity defines God as three distinct but consubstantial persons, God the Father, God the Son (Jesus Christ) and God the Holy Spirit, sharing the same essence.

Whether multiple human persons could share the same substance depends on what you mean by person and substance. If we assume the Christian's notions, then the main attribute of a person is free will, and the substance of a human being is his or her material body. Given this, multiple human persons sharing the same substance would be three persons sharing a unique body. However, how could it be possible that the different persons sharing the same body all enjoy free will? If one person wants to go to London and another to Berlin, the body cannot be split into two bodies one going to London and the other to Berlin. Thus, at least one person's free will will be thwarted. Thus, either one person takes full control or they agree on a system of time-sharing, each person enjoying the full control of the body only for a limited period of time. In both cases, it is not true that that every person enjoys free will, and so we cannot have several persons sharing one body.

We could of course redefine "person" and "substance" differently, but if we assume these definitions, then the same reasoning also applies to and falsifies the doctrine of the Trinity.

Comment: The question has now been edited to ask for a trinitarian perspective. This was implied in the original question, which asked for a Christian perspective. This answer does not answer the question from the specified perspective. Clearly trinitarian Christians would not conclude with reasoning that would falsify the doctrine of the Trinity.